# Computing volume of pits with a variable surface edge in a DEM? Multiple TINS per surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin, volume

I have a DEM of the seafloor. The grid is highly variable, with scour pits throughout the lower right quadrant. I want to compute volume for these pits. It seems all the standard tools such as Cut/Fill using the DEM or Polygon Volume using a TIN (converted from DEM) use a set plane to represent the depth of the second surface. However, the edges of my scour pits have variable depths.

Is the best way to get a true volume to convert each individual scour polygon to a TIN, and then do a cut/fill or some TIN analysis/difference?

Is there a way to do this and have all polygons converted to TINs within a single layer? There are quite a few polygons, so separate layers and analyses would be very time intensive.

I have ArcGIS 10.5 on my Windows VM.

Related question: [How to calculate volume of bund around pit from TIN and external feature edge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/how-to-calculate-volume-of-bund-around-pit-from-tin-and-external-feature-edge)

Looks like they opted to convert polygons to TINs, but unknown If they had to do each one separate or if they found another solution.

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: You may have to do it individually. Multigeometry may work though I never tried;  Create a 3d surface of the variable edge (you can digitize a line then convert the line to 3D using the  Interpolate Shape tool. Convert this to a TIN) Also convert your DEM to TIN and then run the Extrude Between tool to get the enclosed volume between the 2 surfaces. I believe the output is a multipatch feature from which you can obtain the volume.